# Calculate average number in Java

Tags: java, time-series

Below is example of time series data:

```
time - 3 sec, value  - 6 
time - 10 sec, value - 7
time - 12 sec, value - 8
time - 17 sec, value - 9
time - 28 sec, value - 93
time - 29 sec, value - 94
```

I would like to calculate the average value for the last 30 seconds. Is there any simple standard algorithm for that ? Would be nice to see a link to Java implementation as well

Comment: How're you storing the data?

Comment: It could be a Map<Long, Long> for example

Comment: What's your expected output for the given example (i.e. exactly what kind of average are you looking to compute)?

Comment: Are you not allowed to just add them up and divide by the number of items...?

Comment: If i simply sum them and divide by the number of occurrence, it will not be the average per 30 seconds. It should be extrapolated somehow

Comment: Okay, I think you're actually asking a mathematics questions here.

Comment: It would be better if you put this data into db and use the pre-defined function

Comment: It's hard to suggest a meaningful method without understanding how to interpret your data. What would you expect the value to be at t=11s? Also, how would you expect the algorithm to deal with the fact that you're looking for a 30s average but only have 26s worth of data?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote(with a friend) a code that calculates the average number:

```
package dingen;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Gemiddelde {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    float maxCount = 0;
    float avgCount = 0;

    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want");

    int n = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number: ");
        float number = sc.nextInt();
        maxCount = maxCount + number;

    }

    avgCount = maxCount / n;
    System.out.println("maxCount = " + maxCount);
    System.out.println("avgCount = " + avgCount);
}

}
```

the only thing you have to do is replace your class and package.

you will get the message: `How many numbers do you want?:`

and then it wil ask you the amount of numbers you inserted.

example:

> How many numbers do you want?:6
>
> Number:6
>
> Number:7
>
> Number:8
>
> Number:9
>
> Number:93
>
> Number:94
>
> maxCount = 217.0
>
> avgCount = 36.166668

I have hoped I helped you with your problem :)

Comment: This shows how to calculate an average over `n` numbers, but the OP is not asking for that. He's asking how to calculate an average over the last 30 seconds range. Note that in 30 seconds, there might be more, less or exactly 30 entries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [`TreeMap<Integer, Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), with the key being the seconds and the value, well, your value ;)

`TreeMap` has useful methods, such as [`lastKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastKey--) and [`tailMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap-K-), which would fit your use case:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

// add all your entries

Integer lastSecond = map.lastKey(); // returns the highest key

Integer thirtySecondsAgo = lastSecond - 30;

SortedMap<Integer, Integer> range = map.tailMap(thirtySecondsAgo);

int count = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (Integer value : range.values()) {
    sum += value;
    count++;
}

double average = (double) sum / (double) count;
```

`tailMap()` docs:

> Returns a view of the portion of this map whose keys are greater than or equal to `fromKey`

For your problem, `fromKey` would be `thirtySecondsAgo`.